# Download video with sony remote api

Tags: camera, sony, sony-camera-api

I am working on a project which needs to record and download a video with "HS120" movie quality using Sony HDR-AS50.  I only see transfer image from the API but there is no transfer for videos.  Is there any way to download the video file form the camera via wifi?

I am using C# for this project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Image Transfer API works for videos as well as images so you should be able to use it for your purpose.

Comment: Thank you very much!  I didn't realize that I missed the url of the original file when deserializing the JSON data which I can use to download the file. :)